# How to write model class for json data with dictionary?

Tags: ios, swift3

In this class already i had written model class but here some of the data has been added newly but i am trying to create for the model class for remaining dictionaries but unable to implement it  can anyone help me how to implement it ?

In this already i had implemented model class for items array and here i need to create a model class for search criteria dictionary and inside arrays

[image]

```
 func listCategoryDownloadJsonWithURL() {
        let url = URL(string: listPageUrl)!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil { print(error!); return }
            do {
                if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any] {
                    let objArr = jsonObj["items"] as? [[String:Any]]
                    self.list = objArr!.map{List(dict: $0)}
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        let itemsCount = self.list.count
                        for i in 0..<itemsCount {
                            let customAttribute = self.list[i].customAttribute
                            for j in 0..<customAttribute.count {
                                if customAttribute[j].attributeCode == "image" {
                                    let baseUrl = "http://192.168.1.11/magento2/pub/media/catalog/product"
                                    self.listCategoryImageArray.append(baseUrl + customAttribute[j].value)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                        self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                        self.collectionView.isHidden = false
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
struct List {

    let name : String
    let sku : Any
    let id : Int
    let attributeSetId : Int
    let price : Int
    let status : Int
    let visibility : Int
    let typeId: String
    let createdAt : Any
    let updatedAt : Any
    var customAttribute = [ListAttribute]()


    init(dict : [String:Any]) {
        if let customAttribute = dict["custom_attributes"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
            var result = [ListAttribute]()
            for obj in customAttribute {
                result.append(ListAttribute(json: obj as! [String : String])!)
            }
            self.customAttribute = result
        } else {
            self.customAttribute = [ListAttribute]()
        }

        self.name = (dict["name"] as? String)!
        self.sku = dict["sku"]!
        self.id = (dict["id"] as? Int)!
        self.attributeSetId = (dict["attribute_set_id"] as? Int)!
        self.price = (dict["price"] as? Int)!
        self.status = (dict["status"] as? Int)!
        self.visibility = (dict["visibility"] as? Int)!
        self.typeId = (dict["type_id"] as? String)!
        self.createdAt = dict["created_at"]!
        self.updatedAt = dict["updated_at"]!
    }
}
struct ListAttribute {

    let attributeCode : String
    let value : String

    init?(json : [String:String]) {

        self.attributeCode = (json["attribute_code"])!
        self.value = (json["value"])!

    }
}
```

Comment: No big deal... you are almost there. Create another model class for 'search_criteria' just like you have created for 'items'. And wrap both of them into another model class as a result set.

Comment: here comes the problem i had done already as u said but unable to implement it  @Rishi